# How to configure Cassandra on GCE then I can access it from my local java application running on Win7?

Tags: cassandra, google-compute-engine, cassandra-3.0

I created a CentOS on GCE and installed dsc-cassandra 3.0. Then I changed the `rpc_address` from `localhost` to the `internal ip` or `external ip` in cassandra.yaml.
On the VM, I started cassandra and use `cqlsh` to access cassandra successfully. But I couldn't use `cqlsh internal_ip` or `cqlsh external_ip`.
Also, I turned on tcp:9042 port for this instance.

But I still couldn't access Cassandra from my local java app with the NoHostAvailableException(Cannot connect).

By the way, I did the same thing of my local VM running with VM VistualBox. I could access it.

Running `sudo netstat -lntp | grep pid` displayed:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33743         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1207/java           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1207/java           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7199          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1207/java           
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9042          :::*                    LISTEN      1207/java
```

The Ip address was still 127.0.0.1. I think this is the problem.
How to configure the `cassandra.yaml` file?

Answer (score 0):

I know where I was wrong.

I used `sudo service cassandra restart` to restart cassandra after editing the cassandra.yaml. The terminal showed:

```
Restarting cassandra (via systemctl): [  OK  ]
```

Actually, I think it didn't really restart it. Then I used `nodetool stopdaemon` to stop cassandra and then start it again. The configuration of cassandra.yaml worked.

**Helpful commands**:

```
1.
ps aux | grep cassandra
sudo netstat -lntp | grep <cassandra_pid>
```

Using these commands to verify the ip/port of the cassandra service on remote VM.

`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5928/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:42682         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5928/java 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7199          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5928/java
tcp6       0      0 10.138.0.2:9042         :::*                    LISTEN      5928/java`

```
2.
telnet <cassandra_ip> 9042
```

Using this command to verify the ip/port of the cassandra service on local machine.